# Method not found: 'Serilog.LoggerConfiguration

Tags: c#, serilog

I have a main logger for my solution which is defined as

```
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
        .WriteTo.LiterateConsole(LogEventLevel.Verbose)
        .WriteTo.RollingFile($"{appLogDir}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}logs{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}V-RPi-{{Date}}.log")
        .WriteTo.RollingFile($"{appLogDir}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}logs-warnings{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}V-RPi-{{Date}}.log", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .WriteTo.File($"{appLogDir}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}recent-log.log", fileSizeLimitBytes: 134217728, restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Verbose)
        .CreateLogger();
```

I want to create two separate loggers to log things in two class instances. I have defined them as below. This is located in a separate assembly from the main project.

```
private ILogger comRespLog;
public **constructor**(string name)
{
comRespLog = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Verbose()            
                .WriteTo.RollingFile($"{appLogDir}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}logs-CommandResponse-{Name}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}V-RPi-{{Date}}.log")
                .CreateLogger();
}
```

I receive no build errors but I receive this at run time.

> Method not found: 'Serilog.LoggerConfiguration
>   Serilog.RollingFileLoggerConfigurationExtensions.RollingFile(Serilog.Configuration.LoggerSinkConfiguration,
>   System.String, Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel, System.String,
>   System.IFormatProvider, System.Nullable`1<Int64>,
>   System.Nullable`1, Serilog.Core.LoggingLevelSwitch, Boolean,
>   Boolean, System.Nullable`1)'."}

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out I was referencing an older nuget package in my Main Assembly than I was in the sub assembly. After updating them so they match the problem went away.

Comment: Hi @theColonel26 I am facing a similar issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58086137/method-not-found-serilog-loggerconfiguration-serilog-loggerconfigurationlogent . Could you please help me in fixing it.

Comment: For reference, my fix was just to upgrade all Serilog references in nuget to latest version and error went away.  So that was a relatively quick way to fix :)

Answer (score 4):

**Issue due to version mismatch**

Your code is correct just match version

I was using Version 2.0 instead of 1.5

Please match your version with (if you are using Active Directory / Azure Active Directory)

Steps

1. UnInstall Serilog
2. Install Serilog with match version (1.5/ 2.0/..)

Answer (score 0):

Should install the serilog for the netcore framework.

```
dotnet add package Serilog.AspNetCore --version 4.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the workaround was removing references from web.config, as the versions were fixed and still i was facing issues, so I removed the assembly references from the web.config, and thanks to .net compiler, it targets,
as I can think, if a reference is there, to the target interface and hence cannot find things exactly implemented, remove references from web.config of the dll, and the IIS will automatically pick up references from the class file.