# Method not found: 'Serilog.LoggerConfiguration Serilog.LoggerConfigurationLogentriesExtensions.Logentries

Tags: c#, .net-core, runtimeexception, serilog

I am working on a .net core project which uses a nuget package say NUGET 1. The package references serilog for logging purpose. Everything works fine till here. The references of serilog can be seen in the image.

[image]

As soon as I add another nuget package say NUGET 2. The project still builds but this time I get a runtime error below.

> Method not found: 'Serilog.LoggerConfiguration
>   Serilog.LoggerConfigurationLogentriesExtensions.Logentries(Serilog.Configuration.LoggerSinkConfiguration,
>   System.String, Boolean, Int32, System.Nullable`1,
>   Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel, System.String, System.IFormatProvider)'.

The details of second nuget package are in image below. 
I am unable to figure out exact reason for this.

[image]

Comment: Have you setup serilog sinks?

Comment: What are they? I am just trying to use second nuget package.

Comment: I would expect that you somewhere in your code defines that you are using Serilog. If this is API or MVC then typically in your Startup.cs or Program.cs. If you have a piece of code saying .UseSerilog() then you will need to implement at least one sink else that will fail at runtime

Comment: The problem occurs just after adding the nuget package. Without making any changes in code.  Could this be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41187875/method-not-found-serilog-loggerconfiguration ?

Comment: You're going to need to post more code and information. Have you verified that you have no conflicting  versions of serilog? In other words do the packages depend on different versions of serilog?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to difference in version of `serilog` in both nuget packages. I updated the second nuget package to point to same version of `serilog`. This fixed the issue for me. 
The similar problem is also described here [Method not found: 'Serilog.LoggerConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41187875/method-not-found-serilog-loggerconfiguration) and the solution for this is also the same.